# Use FTP Over Hadoop for Large Files

Tags: hadoop, ftp

We want a System that should store huge amount of large csv files(1000 files, each 1GB per day).

And there is some client should connect to this system and download csv files

the system should fault tolerant and scalable...

I think about a Hadoop cluster and run a FTP server over it...

Is Hadoop suitable for this project?

If not, what technology is suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Hadoop Framework is suitable for large size files ( probably where the ingested file size is more than the block size of 256 MB ).

The main advantage of Hadoop is that it could be run on cheap hardware. Hadoop has some problems regarding handling of small files  ( in Kb's ) .

Hadoop provides fault - tolerance as the files would be replicated in the cluster 3 times ( default ), could be increased or decreased.

Hadoop allows distributed processing of the data across the nodes.

It also scales easily.

If you want to copy in between 2 HDFS cluster, there is Distcp process, you
can look into the following link

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-13-x/topics/cdh_admin_distcp_data_cluster_migrate.html

Comment: what about get original file over ftp?
is this normal use case using HDFS?

Comment: If you are copying to another Hadoop Cluster , then there is Hadoop DistCp process . Else you will have to copy to local edge node and then run FTP.

Comment: I do not understand local edge node?
all copy command should run in one node ?

Comment: Edge node is the gateway node for the Hadoop cluster and outside cluster. You can check :- https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-simple-explanation-of-edge-nodes-Hadoop

Comment: so you think hadoop is siutable for our requirement
do you have any real word example that companies use hadoop for such use case ?

Comment: Hadoop Framework is used for cheap storage and processing unstructured/structured data fast. Is there any processing involved or only File Transfer ?

Comment: actually we should run some validation on data. files are csv and validation means validating content of file. for example how many rows in csv that column3 is null and so on... after that we should store this data in database too...

Comment: Then Hadoop Platform will be useful for processing really fast. There are many examples available . There are NOSQL databases also which would help you in storing structured data in HDFS.

Comment: Can you please accept my main answer so that it could be helpful to other people looking for the same info . Thanks.